# Intel 8080 How to convert decimal number to binary and print it

Tags: assembly, intel-8080

i am doing some program in Intel 8080 and in the end i have a number in register E. I need this number convert to binary and print it to terminal.

For now i am printing it like decimal:

```
mov a,e
adi '0' 
call putchar
call newline
hlt
```

Can somebody help me how to do that? Ty

Comment: Converting a number from a variable to individual binary digits for output on 8080 is two separate problems: first, you need an algorithm, which is language independent and which will involve some math to extract individual digits, and, second, you need to implement that algorithm in 8080.  Start with the algorithm, which can be done in any language, then convert to assembly.   Having an algorithm first will tell you what you need to do in assembly.  You don't have to think in assembly to make the algorithm, so do that part in any language you know.

Comment: @ErikEidt Most high level languages doesn't support things like `xor a, a; shr e; adc a, '0'`, although I have no idea if this is valid 8080 assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithm is - rotate number eight times to left. MSB is moved to `CY` flag. According `CY` flag value the digit 1 or 0 is printed.
Code assumes that subroutine `putchar` preserves registers `C` `E`

```
          MVI   c,8   
LOOP:     MOV   a,e   
          RLC           ;rotation to left will print from MSB
          MOV   e,a   
          MVI   a,'0'   
          JNC   zero   
          MVI   a,'1'   
ZERO:     
          CALL   putchar   
          DCR   c   
          JNZ   loop   
          CALL   newline   
          HLT
```

Comment: Thank you, but how could i reverse order? Bcs i need it in format 00000011 .

Comment: I am sorry. I want print from MSB. Unfortunately I use wrong rotation direction to right. This need to be left. Please check updated code.

Comment: If it is ok, please accept answer.